# Is there a simple way to directly define binary numbers? (such as an equivalent to the 0x-notation for hexadecimal numbers)

Tags: java, syntax, binary

If I have the hexadecimal representation of a number, say f2, I can directly store the number as an int using.

```
int num = 0xf2;
```

Then,

```
System.out.println(num);
```

yields the output

```
242
```

What if I instead happen to know that this number is represented in base 2 as 11110010, is there a corresponding way to define an int using this information?

If not, why not? Is is deemed inelegant to work directly with binary representations?

Comment: Integer.parseInt("1100110", 2) returns 102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 7, there are [binary literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/language/binary-literals.html). That said, in many higher level applications working with binary directly is difficult to read and often unnecessary.

Comment: [This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html) works better. Thanks! "0b" it is.